# OverCls is not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, extjs

I am working with extjs 4.2 and need an advice to solve this small bug. I have an extjs button in my js file as:

```
{
        xtype : 'button',
        text : 'Add Drive',
        padding : '10px 10px 10px 10px',
        overCls : 'overDrive'
}
```

and my in my css i have it as:

```
.x-btn.x-overDrive{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: black;
}
```

Now the problem is that this underline is not working in IE browser only. It works everywhere except IE. Am i missing something here? please help!

Comment: really is it working in other browsers? you have added `overDrive` class but in CSS you have mentioned like `x-overDrive`. Is it right??

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai yes, its working in other browsers. This is the way we are suppose to work with classes in extjs

Comment: If this is a bug, can you tell me what version of ExtJS are you using? 4.2.1, 4.2.2, 4.2.3?

Comment: @GuilhermeLopes 4.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your css with:

```
.x-btn.x-overDrive, .x-btn.overDrive .x-btn-inner {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: black;
}
```

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/o5c

Comment: Check the fiddle I added, seems to be working with Chrome and IE 9 to IE 11